# Integrating Jplayer video playback with Angular.JS

Tags: javascript, integration, angularjs, jplayer

I'm working with a framework based on angular.js. I need to playback video and an iframe is off the menu per my customer's specifications.

I am trying to get [jPlayer](http://www.jplayer.org/) video playback working.  I have seen [c0deformer's](http://amitgharat.wordpress.com/2012/11/25/using-jplayer-in-your-angular-application/) solution and I have it integrated already as an audio player, but for my newest project they definately need video playback.  When I start my jPlayer instance, I get the following error:

```
pre-call ClosureCompiler.script:1
post-call ClosureCompiler.script:1
TypeError: Cannot read property 'childNodes' of undefined
    at e (http://arielsmamma/rsrc/3rdparty/angular-1.0.1.min.js:38:220)
    at e (http://arielsmamma/rsrc/3rdparty/angular-1.0.1.min.js:38:215)
    at e (http://arielsmamma/rsrc/3rdparty/angular-1.0.1.min.js:38:215)
    at k (http://arielsmamma/rsrc/3rdparty/angular-1.0.1.min.js:42:261)
    at http://arielsmamma/rsrc/3rdparty/angular-1.0.1.min.js:46:471
    at k (http://arielsmamma/rsrc/3rdparty/angular-1.0.1.min.js:42:261)
    at http://arielsmamma/rsrc/3rdparty/angular-1.0.1.min.js:46:458
    at http://arielsmamma/rsrc/3rdparty/angular-1.0.1.min.js:91:245
    at h (http://arielsmamma/rsrc/3rdparty/angular-1.0.1.min.js:75:256)
    at http://arielsmamma/rsrc/3rdparty/angular-1.0.1.min.js:75:489 angular-1.0.1.min.js:60
pre-setmedia-call ClosureCompiler.script:1
post-setmedia-call
```

Here is the jPlayer code:

```
(function()
{
    itx.ns( 'ui.video.jPlayerVideo', jPlayerVideo, true );
    itx.extend( jPlayerVideo, itx.Directive,
    {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        name: 'itx-jPlayer-video',
        scope: {
            'src': '=',
            'duration': '='
        }
    });


    function jPlayerVideo($scope)
    {
        itx.Directive.apply( this, arguments );
        var self = this;
        console.log('pre-call');
        $("#jp_container_1").jPlayer({
            swfPath: '../rsrc/3rdparty/jplayer/',
            solution: 'flash, html',
            supplied: 'm4v',
            ready: function () {
                console.log('pre-setmedia-call');
                $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
                    m4v: $scope.src
                });
                console.log('post-setmedia-call');
            }
        });
        console.log('post-call');
    }
})()
```

I hope I've given enough information!

Comment: This will be hard to debug without a fiddle or something. Have you tried setting a breakpoint and stepping through the code?

Comment: @blesh I am still fairly new to JS tools, I will investigate how to do this and have a look.  I'm not really sure what I'm looking for, though.

Comment: If anyone can help with this, I can provide a link to the actual site in chat or via email or something?  I really have no idea how to step through Angular's minified code.

Comment: I suggest you to use non minified javascript codes for development.  It should give you more informative errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FWIW, when I got back to this I decided to try other alternatives, and I found that [videoJS](http://videojs.com/) worked perfectly out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should provide a simple example on JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/

Without an live example it's hard to test the code.

Aside of that, I've notices the line:

```
name: 'itx-jPlayer-video',
```

I suppose this is your directive? I'm not sure, but shouldn't it be 'itxJPlayerVideo'?

> Directives have camel cased names such as ngBind. The directive can be invoked by translating the camel case name into snake case with these special characters :, -, or _.

See http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

Comment: When I get back to this task I will try to set up a repro.  I haven't even had time to get to swapping out non-minified versions of the javascript to see if I can step through and get some insight into what's happening here.  Someone else on my team might end up doing it also, if so I will paste the answer here.